# What is the best way to print a report to PDF in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, reporting

I have a complicated report that I need to draw with GDI+ (I don't know of a better way) with multiple pages and have it save to PDF so the user can download. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953179/cost-effective-net-solutions-for-report-generation-in-excel-and-pdf

Comment: Which is the driver, the need to do it in GDI+, or the need to have it in PDF? I once had a project where they were asking for PDF, but they really just wanted to be able to print the page cleanly. We did that by using different style sheets for print and browser.

Comment: The need to have it in PDF. It is an OSHA report file and it has very strict requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how complex your report is and what you are doing with GDI+ but here's some ideas that may help:

Checkout [ITextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) and/or [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/).

The [spark view engine](http://whereslou.com/2009/04/12/returning-pdfs-from-an-aspnet-mvc-action) also has pdf generation built in.

As another thought.... If you have access to SQL Report server and/or at least it's client and can use it to create your report you can generate and call from .Net MVC and output as PDF.

Check out this SO answer:
[Asp.Net MVC how to get view to generate PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779430/asp-net-mvc-how-to-get-view-to-generate-pdf)

Comment: definitely - buy a pre-built component.  They're inexpensive and prolific.

Comment: PDFSharp looks like it will fit my needs perfectly. Thanks

Comment: the link you posted to PDFSharp is apparently an older site.  That site points to the current link: www.pdfsharp.net

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of doing it, install [Bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com) on the server, and using the COM interface, you can programmatically print it out to a pdf document which I would think would be less hassle...simply select the Bullzip PDF Printer as the active printer and print it out to a destination pdf folder. Have a look at this [here](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/doc/info.php) to see how the COM works...the COM interface is the same as bioPDF's COM model.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of [Data Dynamics ActiveReports](http://www.datadynamics.com/) myself. Probably has a little do with the fact that they're local in town, and if I have a problem I can just call them up. Very good reporting engine though. Prints directly to PDF.